# Shape with straight/cutted edges

Tags: java, android, xml, border, shapes

I want to create a background drawable with XML to use it as a background for a `LinearLayout`. I can't find any tutorials for shapes with straight or cutted edges - just round edges. Isn't it possible?

The Shape should look like this:

[image: shape]

Thats my code for a rectangle with round corners:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
  <gradient
    android:startColor="#000"
    android:endColor="#000"
    android:gradientRadius="400"
    android:angle="-270"/>
</shape>
```

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Cheers

Comment: can you show us something you tried?

Comment: are you getting round cornered rectangle with that? that's because the value you put are "radius"

Comment: Yes I do and yeah I know - but whats the attribute name for straight/cutted edges?

Comment: I don't think is possible, you shoud try with an image. Just don't use a image to be resized but nine different images, one is the center, with the grey gradient, four angles, four edges. You need not to stretch the central image but to fill in the gap with copies like a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to create a button with XML to use it as a background.I just cut Image with my Photoshop and implement it in my XML With ImageButton as a background.Hope it may help you to draw round edges Button.
For Example:-

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/answer1"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ans"
```

Comment: I don't need round edges - I need these straight/cutted edges. And to use a finished image file doesn't work for me because it gets stretched and looks ugly if someone uses the app on a device with a bigger display or in landscape mode.

Comment: Yeah! you can get that just by using Alignment and Padding.see My Update answer.